# Using multiple services with Dependency Injection, but only one at a time - question about scopes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scope, garbage-collection, maui

Edited for a more concrete example...

This all relates to Microsoft.Extentions.DependencyInjection...

I have found the information available (both documentation and blogs) for dependency injection to be extremely lacking in the details I want to know. It brings to mind all those memes about unit tests working but integration tests failing - all the documentation/blogs I've found are the unit tests, and no-one has written about integrating different scopes. I've been doing some trial and error, but got to a point where I've realised I would need to make huge changes to my app just to test something out, so I'm hoping someone can provide this info (take this also as a nudge that a blog on this topic would be most welcome).

I have 2 services (might increase to more later, but 2 for now). Let's say they're Chinese Restauraunts with the same menu (beef in black bean sauce, spring rolls, etc.) but different deals on different days or other differences, so some days you order from one place, other days you order from the other place, but you're never ordering from both places, so loading both into memory is wasting memory (especially if you add more restaurants). So we have a common interface IMenu, and 2 services RestaurantA and RestaurantB. I want to be able to select which one to use (from user settings), and ONLY have that one using any memory. Every example I have seen has both RestaurantA and RestaurantB defined as singletons and tells you how to switch between them, but then both of them are taking up memory when I only need one at a time (and even more of a memory issue if/when I add more services).

So, the way I do this without DI is...

```
MenuPage(IMenu menu)
{
string restaurant=Preferences.get("CurrentChoice",default);
switch (restaurant)
    {
    case "RestaurantA":{menu=new RestaurantA();}
    case "RestaurantB":{menu=new RestaurantB();}
    }
}
```

This works fine without DI because if you switch from using A to B, A goes out of scope and gets garbage collected. But...

Further to that, I found that the page you inject has to also be registered (was only mentioned on 1 blog - nowhere else did I ever see this mentioned), so in this case MenuPage itself is registered in DI (either as a singleton, or a scoped service itself, but even if it's scoped, somewhere upstream there's a singleton page, because this is all inside of a MAUI Flyout page, which never goes out of scope).

i.e. in the builder there would be something like...

```
MauiAppBuilder builder=MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services
    .AddSingleton<MAUIFlyoutPage>()
    .AddScoped<MenuPage>()
    .AddScoped<IMenu,RestaurantA>()
    .AddScoped<IMenu,RestaurantB>();
```

So, one thing I did find, but is the fly in the ointment, is if you inject a Scoped service into a Singleton, it effectively becomes a Singleton, because the Singleton never goes out of scope, so it never goes out of scope (logically this makes sense). So whether MenuPage is a singleton or scoped, either way it's inside a singleton FlyoutPage, so it appears to me that the scope gets trapped so no garbage collection happens?

Qualifier, this is all with constructor injection. I saw mentioned somewhere property injection, and maybe this is a way to do it? Asking before I go down another potentially fruitless rabbit hole of singletons and trapped scopes.

Basically I just want to know if there's a way in Dependency Injection to switch between 2 (or more) services, and only have 1 at a time loaded in memory (as opposed to all of them loaded in memory and switching)? As far as I can see it can't be done (not when you have a root page that never goes out of scope, and all pages that you want to be injected into also have to be registered... which eventually bring you back down to the root page).

Comment: A scoped service injected in a sinleton service has a great chance to become invalid when the scope get disposed and the scoped service is disposable.

Comment: It is very common practice in that case to have a factory service that will be injected instead of all services and you can use that get the right service

Comment: Hi @SirRufo, I've seen examples of that, but they all involved singletons. If I have a scoped service, and I use the factory pattern to inject it into a singleton page, will it get garbage collected when I switch services? It's not clear to me if it will or not because no-one ever talks about using scoped services like that.

Comment: 1. When you have a scoped service it will get disposed when the scope is disposed (if it implements IDisposable) 2. When you drop the last reference that instance will gc at some time or if you force it

Comment: When I need a scoped service inside a singleton class (like a Worker), then I would create a scope, ask the scoped service collection for an instance of the service, use that service and when finished I dispose the scope.

Comment: Hey @SirRufo, ok, but the examples I've seen have some something like _service=ServiceA, and then _service=ServiceB, and without DI, ServiceA would definitely get disposed by GC, but using DI, if _service is in a singleton, say ServicePage, then that will never go out of scope, and so, according to the doco, ServiceA will also never go out of scope because ServicePage never goes out of scope, so I'm not clear on what you mean, or if in fact it would go out of scope if _service is reassigned to something else (like it would if not using DI).

Comment: Well, the examples you have seen have nothing to do with my comment. Now you try to understand what I say with examples I did not talk about. In most cases that will fail. - I do told you how I would handle scoped services within a worker

Comment: Yes @SirRufo, and I said I don't understand what you mean by how you would do that. All I know is the examples I've seen, and none of them would work in my scenario, because they all end up getting injected into a singleton. Can you show me an example of what you mean? I don't know how you can call a scoped service from a singleton and/or non-DI page - the former won't get disposed and the latter simply doesn't work to begin with. This is exactly what my question is about - how do you do that? (if in fact it's even possible)

Comment: I have written a very bare example on how to use a scoped service in a singleton service https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/7233e84f6f39d2a0bb13442f10960f1a

Comment: I tried to understand what you're asking, but the question is quite vague. Could you clarify this by adding concrete examples of `ServiceA`, `ServiceB`, their consumers, and their usage. And describe how `ServiceA`, `ServiceB` are related (e.g. do share the same interface?) Also important: do those user settings change at runtime, or are they fixed after startup?

Comment: Thanks @SirRufo, I didn't know about CreateScope before, but you've put it in a DoSomething, which to me sounds like a TransientService, not a ScopedService? I'm specifically looking how to have a ScopedService. i.e. stays in scope for the lifetime of the page it's being used in, and I don't quite see how to make that work in this case, only how to make it work as a TransientService.

Comment: Hi @Steven, yes my apologies for not being clear about that - yes, they have a shared interface, so you can have IService=ServiceA/B. If you're not using DI, then ServiceA goes out of scope when you assign it to ServiceB, but I'm not sure how to make that work with DI since IService never goes out of scope.

The user changes the setting, which is then saved to the device. i.e. Preferences.Set("CurrentService",SelectionType). When the page is initialised it gets which service to use - Preferences.Get("CurrentService"). About to go to bed but will edit the question tomorrow to be clearer. Thx!

Comment: The FooService is your Singleton service and can consume a scoped service or any other scoped dependency for IBarService. Why does it matter in which method the code is? It is the shortest code to show you how to get a scoped service and use it. If it is too vague for you, then you should not ask too vague questions

Comment: Hey @Steven I've edited the question now - I hope that's clearer what I mean?

Comment: @SirRufo ah ok, but then that still looks like a Transient service to me. i.e. the service is only called when you call a method. I think the crossed wires is MS using "scope" to mean 2 different things. I don't mean "scope" like in a using (though happy to see a way you can use that) - i.e. memory is allocated every time - I mean a DI scoped service. i.e. builder.Services.AddScoped<ServiceA>;as opposed to builder.Services.AddTransient<ServiceA>;
So because your code is inside a DoSomething, that looks to me like a Transient service. i.e. called up every time you want to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to solve the problem:

```cs
public sealed class MenuProxy : IMenu
{
    // This class depends on the Contianer and should, therefore, be part of your
    // application's Composition Root (see https://mng.bz/K1qZ).
    private readonly IServiceProvider container;
    
    public MenuProxy(IServiceProvider container) => this.container = container;

    private IMenu GetMenu()
    {
        string restaurant=Preferences.get("CurrentChoice",default);
        switch (restaurant)
        {
            case "RestaurantA": return this.GetRestaurant<RestaurantA>();
            case "RestaurantB": return this.GetRestaurant<RestaurantB>();
        }
    }

    private T GetRestaurant<T>() => this.container.GetRequiredService<T>();

    // Map all IMenu methods here to the GetMenu() method.
    public Appetizer[] GetAppetizers() => this.GetMenu().GetAppetizers();
}
```

Registration:

```cs
MauiAppBuilder builder=MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services
    .AddSingleton<MAUIFlyoutPage>()
    .AddScoped<MenuPage>()
    .AddScoped<RestaurantA>()
    .AddScoped<RestaurantB>()
    .AddScoped<IMenu, MenuProxy>();
```

This ensures the following thing:

- `MenuProxy` can be injected into consumers as `IMenu`. This allows consumers to stay ignorant of the fact that multiple `IMenu` implementations exist in the background
- `MenuProxy` will resolve the required restaurant implementation based on the user choice, preventing the other from being loaded when not needed
- As `RestaurantA` and `RestaurantB` are registered using `AddScoped`, only one instance of the restaurant will exist in mememory for the duration of a single scope, independently of how often `IMenu`'s and `MenuProxy`'s methods are called.
- By placing `MenuProxy` inside the application's [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ) you prevent the application from applying the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://mng.bz/WaQw).

Comment: Hi Steven. Thanks for that. It's late here now, so I'll have a look through all your code tomorrow to digest what is going on (using a few things I haven't seen before). I like right away that you mentioned avoiding an anti-pattern, because one of the issues with the documentation is they talk about avoiding anti-patterns, but then having said that don't tell you what pattern to follow! In fact, pretty much impossible to find anything at all about patterns to use for Scoped and Transient (hence ending up asking the question about it here). Have you thought about writing a blog on this topic?

Comment: Hi @donaldp, I wrote a [whole book](https://mng.bz/BYNl) on the topic of DI actually ;-)

Comment: Thanks Steven. I've read through your links (very helpful thanks!) and then the code, but there's still a missing piece for me - the pattern for MenuPage to begin with. If we use constructor injection for it, then FlyoutPage still holds a reference to it, so it's still a trapped scope, correct? That's my understanding from the doco, which is what led me to ask the question here. If the root page is a singleton (and we can't inject anything unless it's registered), then everything underneath it will be trapped scopes?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what a [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) is. I always found this a tricky problem that basically exists with all UI frameworks where the 'screen' components (view models, pages, etc) can live for a very long time. The only satisfying solution I myself found that solves this Captive Dependency issue with those frameworks is by abstracting away all logic from the 'screen' components behind generic 'handler' abstractions.

Comment: See [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/commands/) and [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/queries/) for instance.

Comment: This solves the problem, because those abstractions allow you to hide management of scopes from both the 'screen' and the 'handler' in a cross-cutting concern (the handler's decorator). Downside of this model, however, that many developers find it difficult to wrap their head around it, and it's not something I recommend for developers new to programming. It can also be hard apply these patterns to already existing applications.

Comment: Yet another downside is that not all DI Containers have good support for type of design. With MS.DI, for instance, you'll have a hard time applying decorators to those handlers. MS.DI makes this excruciatingly difficult, although libraries like Scrutor and MediatR might help in this case. Or you can switch to DI Containers like Autofac and (my own) Simple Injector to ease the pain.

Comment: But I hope you accept the fact that I won't try to solve the Captive Dependency problem for you in this answer, as this takes quite some time and effort to write a good answer that addresses this in the context of the solution with the 'handler' abstractions. If you're interested, do read the links I provided in my earlier comments.

Comment: I'll check out the links later - thanks for that! So, to clarify, using your answer, will those scoped services get captured then, or it manages to avoid that? That was the crux of my question - I know how to solve it without DI, just DI doesn't seem to be able to handle it (well, not the native MS implementation anyway). I ran into mention of handlers in regards to a current MAUI issue with ellipsis menu binding, so something I want to try and get my head around (but not finding many good resources on it yet) - everything I found so far assumes you only want to set once, as opposed to bind.

Comment: "just [MS.DI] doesn't seem to be able to handle it". Well, that's not completely true. It's true that MS.DI is limited in many ways, but as others mentioned, technically, with MS.DI, you create a new `IServiceScope` (`provider.CreateScope()`) from the root container and resolve instances from that `IServiceScope`. This allows you to use scoped services from within the context of a singleton. The difficulty here is, from a design perspective, to do this in a maintainable fashion without tightly coupling consumers to the DI Container, which is the whole idea behind DI: loose coupling.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I don't think that was ever mentioned in the doco. As I said, the doco only ever uses singleton examples - they don't tell you how to handle scoped services... except "don't inject into a singleton" (so I ended up here to try and find out how to use them with a singleton). I think they've read too many books that say "we leave that as an exercise for the reader"...

Comment: I think MS.DI was especially documented for web application scenarios, where it was initially designed for. In web applications, the root objects (typically controllers) only live for a short period of time, which makes these kinds of challenges almost non-existing.

Comment: Well yeah maybe, but the whole MS "Learn" experience is just horrible. This isn't an isolated example of awful documentation there. Most of the time I can work it out cos I already know something about the topic, but I'm learning about DI for the first time, so the issues with the doco are glaringly bad and difficult to work-around (I only found out about the page has to be registered too from 1 non-MS blog post that mentioned it or I'd probably still be getting errors and not know why).

Comment: If MS.DI is bothering you, you can always try to apply Dependency Injection without the use of a DI Container, such as MS.DI. This is a practice sometimes called [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). In that case, you're just applying all DI's principles, patterns, and practices without automating the process of object composition. This can be very helpful in understanding DI, without being limited by technology. Unfortunately, however, I'm too inexperienced with MAUI to describe how to do this by hand while using that framework.

Comment: Well that just sounds like what I was doing already. I was using constructor injection, but without a container. I wasn't sure why people were, but then I ran into an issue and thought using a container might solve it. Turned out I can solve it anyway just with the restructuring of the app I did to accommodate using a container, so I can pretty much just go back to doing it without the container - seems to be more trouble than it's worth, but I did want to make sure I understood everything (like how to use scoped services) before writing it off. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: DI Containers solve one thing, and one thing only, which is they make (or keep) your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) maintainable. All other benefits (maintainability, testability, flexability, etc of the rest of your application) come from Dependency Injection (as a set of principles, practices, and patterns).

Answer (score -1):

> as far as I can see, there's actually no way to achieve this if you're using dependency injection (so I may need to just rip all that out)?
>
> Qualifier, this is all with constructor injection. I saw mentioned
> somewhere property injection, and maybe this is a way to do it? Asking
> before I go down another potentially fruitless rabbit hole of
> singletons and trapped scopes.

You are about to make very huge design mistake, based on your complete misunderstanding of scopes, and the idea that some injected service is consuming HUGE amount of your memory.

You will barely see any difference, no matter how many services you inject. And even if it was a problem, there are better design patterns than:

```
a = new A();
b = new B();
c?service=a:service=b;
```

Sir Rufo, gave you very good example how a scoped service can be used in singleton service. I still do not understand why you did not like it.

I am saying this because there is no such thing as "trapped scopes", "temporarily-scoped pages", etc. And one of the quickest ways to create serious problems in your project, is to try to fix non-existing ones.

In the past it would take me so much time... so much, to implement something that mimics a portion of this Dependency Injection we have in MAUI.  Now you have this tool ready to use, with one line of code, and you refuse to use it, because some imaginary memory concerns.

I advise, against it. Ignore my comment, if you want.
But this is one of the most powerful tools we have.

Comment: It's not an imaginary concern - it's in the documentation, in multiple places. Here's the first one I found just now - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines, see "Captive dependency" (but I've  seen referred to as trapped scopes elsewhere). But having said don't do that, they haven't given an example of how you can use a scoped service with singleton pages. As I said, it looks to me like you can't (which is maybe why there's no examples of it), so I'm asking if you can.

Comment: @donaldp So, I have few clients connected, each with its own scope, and for some reason, I decide that my singleton service will have reference to the scoped service of client No.5? For what reason?!? If I write such non-sense dependency injection will be the least of my concerns. Also, what is "singleton pages"? Pages are views. Views can get destroyed by the OS any time, or recreated, or anything. Some OS limit their usage further, for example making them have a single parent. You really should check some app architectures.

Comment: A singleton page is a page which has been registered as a singleton. Not sure what else you want me to say - thought that was self-explanatory. If you inject a scoped service into a singleton page then according to the doco it won't ever go out of scope, hence the query about how you can use a scoped service when you have singleton pages. There are no examples of it anywhere (the doco even fails to tell you in the first place that the pages have to be registered as well).

Comment: @donaldp how do you define the "scoped service". Scoped to what? What is the object, you are trying to match the lifetime of your services to?

Comment: As per the O.P.
MauiAppBuilder builder=MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services
    .AddSingleton<MAUIFlyoutPage>()
    .AddScoped<MenuPage>()
    .AddScoped<IMenu,RestaurantA>()
    .AddScoped<IMenu,RestaurantB>();

Comment: @donaldp ok, good. And what do you think "scoped" will do here? When is the service created, and when is the service going out of scope?

Comment: When the MenuPage is created. The issue is it's created from the FlyoutPage, which never goes out of scope, so the MenuPage never goes out of scope, and the services never go out of scope, hence my original question - how can you used scoped services when your root page is a singleton.

Comment: @donaldp How can a scoped service be created from another page? When you ask for scoped service to be provided, it checks if such object is created for you current page, and its lifetime gets bound to your page lifetime. How are you doing this injection of scoped from one page to another?

Comment: I'm not because I don't know how to - welcome to my original question.

Comment: @donaldp You know, you convinced me. I am sure now, that for you specifically, removing the dependency injection and writing ifs and switches is much better choice.